# "Hello, World" in PHP displays nothing

Tags: php

I am new to PHP, just downloaded it, and wrote a ["Hello, World!"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program) program:

```
<html>
    <body>

    <?php
        $fileName = "test.jpg";
        $txt = "Hello, World!";
        echo $txt;
    ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't work. I named the file `test.php` and opened it with Firefox and nothing was displayed.

Comment: Did you open through localhost or just from the filesystem (file://) ?

Comment: Also, what webserver? Apache or IIS or ?

Comment: Apache works on most OS, and is relatively easy to install. It's also free (not only as in free beer) and works well with PHP

Comment: if you are brand new to php then you might also consider trying some python web development platform or ruby-rails and see which is better for you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You'll have to pass it through a webserver of some kind, for example [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) or [Apache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server), for it to work.

PHP is a server-side language, thus you can't just open the PHP file in a browser. Instead, try googling some free PHP hosts, and upload your files there.

You could for example go for these solutions that will provide you with what you need:

- WAMP - http://www.wampserver.com/en/ (Windows)
- XAMPP - http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html - (Windows, Mac, and Linux)

Those solutions will install Apache, [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) and PHP and allow you to play locally with PHP development. Later on, if you want to deploy your code, you will have to find an external host (or host it on your own computer).

Comment: You are right, I didnt open it with a websever - the short online tutorial didnt say anything about that. Will try WAMP. Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 6):

You need to have a webserver that you open it through. Simply entering file:///whatever.php does not work, because the file is not parsed by PHP then.

There are several web servers you can chose from, but my advice is [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/), the worlds most popular webserver. I have it running on my Windows XP laptop along with PHP, and it's easy to install and setup, and works great. There are lots of modules that can be installed later if you need them. It's also free, not only as in free beer, but also as in open source.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to install a webserver on your machine to make it work. Take a look at [XAMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP) at http://www.apachefriends.org/en/index.html.

Answer (score 2):

If you have [command-line PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php) installed, you should be able to enter:

```
php test.php
```

to invoke PHP to run your program and display the output on the console.

Answer (score 2):

You need a webserver to view the PHP program like [XAMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP) or [WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP). If you are using XAMPP, put your file in htdocs and then access your file from any browser like Google Chorme, Firefox or Internet Explorer by typing `localhost/foldername/yourfile.php`, in your case `localhost/test.php`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a local server installed? PHP is a server-side scripting language, so it cannot just be run like a normal HTML file.

Try watching the first few videos on the [New Boston's PHP series](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=11). They show you simply how to download, install and use a local server to run your PHP on.