# How to print in PHP blank page

Tags: php

I am trying to learn php and have the following code:

```
<?php

print it "Hello, World!";

?>
```

I am getting a blank page.  Why is this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hello World in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739804/hello-world-in-php)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unlike python, printing in php is done with the `echo` statement.  In order to execute your code, you would do:

```
<?php

echo "Hello, World!";

?>
```

You can check out a great beginner tutorial on php [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/).

```
<?php


print("Hello World");

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

if `short_open_tag` set to `On` in `php.ini` then use

```
<?="Hello World";?>
```

If not, use

`<?php echo "Hello World"; ?>`

Default setting for `short_open_tag` in `php.ini` in XAMPP is `Off`

Comment: `<?php echo "Hellow World"; ?>`

Comment: Why don't you add that to the answer then? Might be nice to remove spelling mistakes too.

Comment: More (relevant) info is always better than not enough. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to echo something very simple:

```
<?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?>
```

A reason you might get a blank page is because you have set up the file permissions incorrectly.
To fix this in your terminal:
`cd WHERE_THE_DIRECTORY_IS`
 then 
`chmod 755 NAME_OF_FILE`

Comment: I run always run windows.  Thanks anyway though!

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help :( @AlexRodrigo